# Export JSON to excel file

Tags: javascript, json, excel

I am having trouble exporting correctly. At first it was not exporting to the right rows...now it only fills in the headers being a1, b1, c1, d1. In my JSON file i have 320 pairs that are {"Result", 132.23}(they change the float for each value but that's it) and then an other 320 pairs that say {"Temp":0},{"Temp":1},{"Temp":2},{"Temp":3},{"Temp":4},{"Temp":5} and so on. Any idea why these are not exporting at all? and possibly how to get all results to col1 starting a2 and then all temps to col2 starting at b2?

I have tried arranging and rearraigning the orderInputArray and orderInputObject obsject and I have tried calling different arrays and object to the first parameter of
exportUsersToExcel(myArr, workSheetColumnName, workSheetName, filePath);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
so either here is my code
////////////////////////////

````
const fs = require("fs");
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const path = require('path');
//////////////////////////////
var Ro = 99.9460;
var myTemp = 320;
var delta = 1.445956;
var alpha = 0.00392352;
/////////////////////////////
var myArr = [];
function rvt(Ro, alpha, T, delta){
  for(i = T; i > -1; --i){
  var rvt1 = Ro * (1 + alpha * (T - delta * (T / 100) * (T / 100 - 1)));
  var rvt1rnd = Math.round((rvt1 + Number.EPSILON) * 10000) / 10000;
  myArr.push(rvt1rnd);
  --T;
  } 
  return myArr;
}
var forrealsfin = rvt(Ro, alpha, myTemp, delta);
////////////////
var orderInputArray = [];
var tempArr = [];
// console.log(myArr);
for(i = myTemp; i > -1; --i){
  tempArr.push(i);
}
// for(i = myTemp; i > -1; --i){  
//         orderInputArray.push("Result")
//         orderInputArray.push(myArr[i]);
//         orderInputArray.push("Temp")
//         orderInputArray.push(tempArr[i]);
// }
for(i = myTemp; i > -1; --i){  
  orderInputArray.push("Result")
  orderInputArray.push(myArr[i]);
}
for(i = myTemp; i > -1; --i){  
orderInputArray.push("Temp")
orderInputArray.push(tempArr[i]);
}

const orderInputObjects = [];
orderInputArray.forEach(function(v, i, a) {
  if(i % 2) orderInputObjects.push({ [a[i - 1]]: v});
});
// console.log(typeof myJson);
// console.log(typeof orderInputArray);
// console.log(typeof orderInputObjects);
// // console.log(orderInputArray);
// process.exit();
// var myJSONob = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArr));
myJson = JSON.stringify(orderInputObjects);
fs.writeFile("myjson.json", myJson, function(err) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
});
// console.log(typeof myArr);
// console.log(typeof myJSONob);
// console.log(typeof orderInputArray);
// console.log(typeof orderInputObjects);
// process.exit();

const workSheetColumnName = [
  "Result",
  "Temp",
  "Alpha", 
  "Delta"
]
const workSheetName = 'resultpage'; // worksheet name
const filePath = './users.xlsx';

//make sample data below or add json file path
const UserList = [{}];
const exportUsersToExcel = (myArr, workSheetColumnName, workSheetName, filePath) => {
  const data = myArr.map( user => {
    return [user.result, user.Temp, user.Alpha, user.Delta];
  });


// console.log(myJson);
// process.exit();
//console.log(myArr);
  const workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const workSheetData = [
    workSheetColumnName,
    ...data
  ];

  const workSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(workSheetData);
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, workSheetName);
  XLSX.writeFile(workBook, path.resolve(filePath));
  return true;

}



exportUsersToExcel(myArr, workSheetColumnName, workSheetName, filePath);```
````

Comment: **either way here is my code**

Comment: Have you built a JSON file by hand with sample values and does it export correctly? And then, have you compared the JSON generated by your code to the sample JSON to find the differences?

Comment: I mean its 640 pairs. But yes I have tried just writing say 10 pairs(set the temp to 5) and still no results. Except the headers where it says Result, Temp, Alpha, Delta. so my workSheetColumnName is exporting correctly but not the data from the JSON.

Comment: I think it would help to post a limited sample of the JSON produced, and what you think it should look like.

Comment: [{"Result":99.946},{"Result":100.3438},{"Result":100.7414},{"Result":101.1389},{"Result":101.5363},{"Temp":0}, {"Temp":1},{"Temp":2},{"Temp":3},{"Temp":4},{"Temp":5}]   so I need result: 99.946 to go in col1 row 2 and have the rest of the results go on each column and then I need Temp : 0 to match and then Result: 100.3438 to match with Temp :1 so i need all the Results  to go col1 starting A2 and all temps to go col2 starting b2.

Comment: The sample JSON looks like it should be okay, but without seeing the code in `exportUsersToExcel`, it's not possible to tell what the actual problem is.

Comment: Normally you would have each object (thing in curly brackets) correspond to a row of your dataset, for example `[{Result: 100.34, Temp: 0, otherprops...}, {Result: 101, Temp: 1, ...}]`

Comment: const exportUsersToExcel = (myArr, workSheetColumnName, workSheetName, filePath) => {
  const data = myArr.map( user => {
    return [user.result, user.Temp, user.Alpha, user.Delta];
  });


// console.log(myJson);
// process.exit();
//console.log(myArr);
  const workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const workSheetData = [
    workSheetColumnName,
    ...data
  ];

  const workSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(workSheetData);
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, workSheetName);
  XLSX.writeFile(workBook, path.resolve(filePath));
  return true;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel's `aoa_to_sheet` function wants an array of arrays.  Here is a simple way to modify your code to generate the dataset needed. The JSON file part didn't seem relevant so I removed it for the sake of simplicity.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const path = require('path');
//////////////////////////////
var Ro = 99.9460;
var myTemp = 320;
var delta = 1.445956;
var alpha = 0.00392352;
/////////////////////////////

function rvt(Ro, alpha, T, delta){
  var myArr = []; // keep this variable local
  for(i = T; i > -1; --i){
    var rvt1 = Ro * (1 + alpha * (T - delta * (T / 100) * (T / 100 - 1)));
    var rvt1rnd = Math.round((rvt1 + Number.EPSILON) * 10000) / 10000;
    myArr.push([rvt1rnd, i, alpha, delta]); // add an array containing all the data for this row
    --T;
  } 
  return myArr;
}
var forrealsfin = rvt(Ro, alpha, myTemp, delta);

const workSheetColumnName = [
  "Result",
  "Temp",
  "Alpha", 
  "Delta"
]
const workSheetName = 'resultpage'; // worksheet name
const filePath = './users.xlsx';

//make sample data below or add json file path
const UserList = [{}];
const exportUsersToExcel = (data, workSheetColumnName, workSheetName, filePath) => {

  const workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  data.unshift(workSheetColumnName); // add the column names array to the beginning of the data

  const workSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, workSheetName);
  XLSX.writeFile(workBook, path.resolve(filePath));
  return true;

}

exportUsersToExcel(forrealsfin, workSheetColumnName, workSheetName, filePath);
```

Comment: TY tons this basically fixed it for me. The only issue now it that it is writing the alpha and delta values continuously. I think I can find a way to push the results onto the array so they only display in col's 3 and 4 but if you know what im doing wrong id apricate a point in the correct direction....either way thank you so much